# Fatal Error Onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I'm using Magento Version 19.2.4 and a custom theme from TemplateMonster,

The shop is online since a few years and all patches are installed. For some reason, today when clicking Checkout, this error message comes up:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getQuote() on boolean in /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php on line 195

This is the code on line 195:

```
$quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
```

This is the report created today:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:53:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in , line 0";i:1;s:1053:"#0 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1265): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/customers/webs/rossi/shop/index.php(77): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/api/xmlrpc";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"english";}
```

Does anyone have an idea how this can happen? I have also cleared the cache.

Any advice would be really helpful.